# How to execute multi-line powershell command

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

Trying to execute a PowerShell command in asp.net c# but it returns no results, where am I going wrong?

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
var script = $@"$Groups = Get-ADGroup {groupname}; $members = ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {{Get-AdGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive}} ; $members | Get-AdUser -Properties Department | Select-Object Name, Department | Sort Department, Name";
shell.Commands.AddScript(script);
var results = shell.Invoke();

foreach (var psObject in results)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { psObject.Members["Name"].Value, psObject.Members["Department"].Value });
}

Gridview2.DataSource = dt;
Gridview2.DataBind();
```

It executes perfectly in PowerShell.  Separating the command over lines as per [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187464/execute-multiple-line-powershell-script-from-c-sharp) does not work.

Edit - I took another look at my powershell and realised that it was unecessarily complicated.  I changed it to the below and it now works.  Still does not explain why something that returns results in powershell does not work when ran from asp.net.

```
Get-AdGroupMember -Identity {groupname} -Recursive | Get-AdUser -Properties Department | Select-Object Name, Department | Sort Department, Name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute multiple line PowerShell Script from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187464/execute-multiple-line-powershell-script-from-c-sharp)

Comment: @Jaxi I had tried that solution but it does not change the outcome.

Comment: Your script is assigning variables with a result. You need to echo the variable to the end to get those results. put `$results` at the end of your script or "var results" or whatever prints it in asp.net

Comment: @RobertCotterman I don't include how I handle the results as I know that part works.  After the invoke I have a foreach which creates a datatable.

Comment: I'm not doubting your knowledge. Sorry if it felt that way. What my point was, is that if you're not asking for an output, you won't get one.

Comment: @RobertCotterman My reply to you was obviously far too blunt, it didn't feel in any way that you doubted my knowledge (which is very limited).  I have edited my code to include the handling of results.  I have an identical working method with the only difference being the powershell, I'm sure it must be something to do with a nuance of executing powershell in this way.