# Multiple lined Powershell block from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Using this code to run my Powershell code from C#, everything works fine

```
        using(PowerShell powershellCommand = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershellCommand.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Path_to_script")).Invoke();
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> results = powershellCommand.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject result in results)
            {
                logg.AppendText(result + ""); 
            }
        }
```

Code in scriptfile.

```
$env:tmp = "env_location"
Import-PSSession $(New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 
server_url) | Out-Null
$device = Get-Mailbox -Identity IDENTITY | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object TotalItemSize

return $device
```

IDENTITY is the problem here since i want it to be dynamic so it can't be hard coded into the scriptfile.
I have tried the solution in [Execute multiple line PowerShell Script from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187464/execute-multiple-line-powershell-script-from-c-sharp) like so:

```
        using(PowerShell powershellCommand = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            string script = @"
            $env:tmp = 'env_location'
            Import-PSSession $(New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri server_url) | Out-Null
            $device = Get-Mailbox -Identity DYNAMIC_IDENTITY | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object TotalItemSize

            return $device
            ";

            powershellCommand.AddScript(script)).Invoke();
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> results = powershellCommand.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject result in results)
            {
                logg.AppendText(result + ""); 
            }
        }
```

It feels like this should work, but there is no output at all. No crash either, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Surely you just want Identity to be a variable in your PowerShell script and then [pass it as a parameter to that script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameter?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) in your dotnet program?

Comment: Also, it seems you're calling invoke twice on your PowerShell command. When I've had to call a script in the past from a dotnet app, if I am expecting output from PowerShell, I have tended to use [`BeginInvoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.begininvoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and `EndInvoke()` instead.

Comment: @Ash Thank you, yes that would be great but I don't understand the syntax for it. I have tried:

powershellCommand.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"path_to_script")).AddCommand("Get-Mailbox").AddParameter("Identity","test-identity");

and:

powershellCommand.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"path_to_script")).AddParameter("$variable_in_script","test-identity");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments above, try this out.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace PowerShellSample
{
    public class Exchange
    {
        public static Collection<PSObject> GetTotalMailboxSize(string identity)
        {
            using(PowerShell powershellCommand = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powershellCommand.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Path_to_script")).AddParameter("Identity", identity);
                IAsyncResult poshTask = powershellCommand.BeginInvoke();
                Collection<PSObject> returnCollection = new Collection<PSObject>();
                foreach (PSObject psObj in powershellCommand.EndInvoke(poshTask))
                {
                    returnCollection.Add(psObj);
                }
                return returnCollection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PowerShell script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [System.String]
    $Identity
)

$env:tmp = "env_location"
Import-PSSession $(New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri server_url) | Out-Null
$Device = Get-Mailbox -Identity $Identity | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object TotalItemSize

return $device
```

If you wanted to provide more parameters you can do so using a `Dictionary<string, Object>` in the method. This way you could pass your ConnectionUri or any other parameters you might need.

```cs
public static Collection<PSObject> GetTotalMailboxSize(string identity, Dictionary<string, Object> parameters)
{
    using(PowerShell powershellCommand = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershellCommand.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Path_to_script"));
        foreach (var key in parameters.Keys)
        {
            powershellCommand.AddParameter(key, parameters[key]);
        }
        IAsyncResult poshTask = powershellCommand.BeginInvoke();
        Collection<PSObject> returnCollection = new Collection<PSObject>();
        foreach (PSObject psObj in powershellCommand.EndInvoke(poshTask))
        {
            returnCollection.Add(psObj);
        }
        return returnCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for taking the time to show me this :) .